# Subscribing to Object value or associated change

Tags: mdriven

Is there some doco on IAutoSubscriptionService.
How do I use     using (ESP.GetEcoService().StartSubscribe(subscriber)) to trigger an event when an object changes. That is for any attribute of an object.

Answer (score 0):

The StartSubscribe gives a IDisposable context back and it is typically used like this:

```
using (theAutoSubscriptionService.StartSubscribe(subscriber))
{
     arbitrary c# code accessing model elements 
     - all access will be added to subscription! 
     A thing of beauty really!
}
```

When something later change - the ISubscriber.Receive will fire.
For adhoc usage consider the EventSubscriber class

Comment: What is the purpose of bool ISubscriber.IsAlive() and int ISubscriber.HashKey

Comment: Subscribers are kept as weakreferences to avoid locking GC - the IsAlive of the ISubscriber is the weakreference.IsAlive exposed - if false we dont notify it - and we clean if from the publishers list when discovered

Comment: Publishers (anything subscribable) can potentially get a lot of subscribers - we keep them in a dictionary on their hashkey - since they are weakreferences we cannot trust to use its existence in a hashlist